# Why does glob return an empty list from this file directory?

Tags: python, glob

I simply can't understand why glob is returning an empty list from this directory I'm giving it. I'm just trying to select all files in my downloads folder in order to select the most recent one. I've even attached an image of the directory to one of the files in the folder I'm looking for, and you'll see that [my directory is correct.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CirHw.jpg) Is something wrong with my syntax?

Here's my very simple code:

```
import glob

list_of_files = glob.glob('/Softdrive/Users/[secretuser]/Downloads/*')
print (list_of_files)
```

I've also tried selecting specific files in Downloads using the exact file names and that also returns an empty list. What's going on?

Comment: are you sure this is a system path and not /Users/[secretuser]/Downloads/* ?
In other words - how do you access this path from the terminal?

Comment: @matiit If I drag a file into the terminal it gives me that directory, so I think so? I'm not sure how else to go about accessing the path from the terminal EDIT: Ah, I see what you're saying. You're right, it was /Users...

Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I am happy that it worked.